# How to 'delay' observable sequence by one value?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

In Reactive Extensions, how can I 'delay' an observable sequence by one value? For example:

```
original: 2 3 5 7 9   
delayed:    2 3 5 7
```

To be clear, I want to delay the sequence by one step. This isn't the same as delaying by a constant time.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var delayedByOne = source.Zip(source.Skip(1), (x, _) => x);
```

But you may need to do this to avoid running two concurrent sources if you have a cold observable source:

```
var delayedByOne = source.Publish(s => s.Zip(s.Skip(1), (x, _) => x));
```

Answer (score 3):

No publish required, but it needs to be in a method to get nice type inference like so:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> DelayByOne<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Scan(
            Tuple.Create(default(T), default(T)),
                (a, i) => Tuple.Create(i,a.Item1))
            .Select(a => a.Item2).Skip(1);
    }
}
```

This idea originated from this http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=213#comment-884. You can see the above is really a specialization of more general comparison function. From the comments to my original blog post, here's the revised utility function for comparing current and prior events:

```
// The result selector is passed (curr, prev) and
// prev is default(T) for first event
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TResult> CombineWithPrevious<TSource, TResult>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource,TSource,TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return source.Scan(
            Tuple.Create(default(TSource), default(TSource)),
                (a, i) => Tuple.Create(i,a.Item1))
            .Select(a => resultSelector(a.Item1, a.Item2));
    }
}
```

So you could use the above like so:

```
var delayedByOne = source.CombineWithPrevious((x,y) => y).Skip(1);
```

Comment: This doesn't work - if I source this with `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))` the first value out is `1`, not `0`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Good spot - I was being over-zealous on the code-golf. This works now I think!

Comment: I just had a thought - would doing `source.StartWith(-1L).Scan((a, i) => a = i).Skip(1);` be simpler? (Except you'd still need to have a `default(T)`.)

Comment: I don't think the `DelayByOne` extension method will work. The `Scan` operator isn't doing any pairing, it's just always pushing through the value that it receives. Your second example seems correct to me though.

Comment: @DaveSexton You are right, I must have been half asleep this morning ;) I've reverted the DelayByOne to it's original version (which also makes the more useful second part less of a non-sequitur anyway). Ta!

Comment: @Enigmativity Fyi - Also see the alternative answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Just realized there's an even neater shorter approach:

```
var delayedByOne = source.Publish(ps => ps.Delay(_ => ps));
```